# How change l backgroundcolor of button theme,text color and height in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm using Button theme in my project im not able to change the backgroundcolor,text color and also im not able to reduce the height of the button theme can someone please look in to it.

Here's my code:

```
Widget _signInButton() {


    return ButtonTheme(

     minWidth: 325,

      child: OutlineButton(
        splashColor: Colors.grey,
        onPressed: () {
          signInWithGoogle().whenComplete(() {
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) {
                  return FirstScreen();
                },
              ),
            );
          });
        },
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40)),
        highlightElevation: 0,
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 10),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Image(image: AssetImage("Assets/google_logo.png"), height: 35.0)),
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                  child: Text(
                    'Sign in with Google',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15,
                      color: Colors.grey,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding `height: 8.0` or `layoutBehavior:ButtonBarLayoutBehavior.constrained` in `ButtonTheme`.
With any one of these options, you can adjust the height and padding of the button.

**Note:** adjust the height value as you please. I have set it to 8.0 as an example

You can use `buttonColor` property in `ButtonTheme` for changing the button's color. Or the `color` property in Child Button should do the work.

But since you are using an `OutlineButton` it won't work as it has no area to paint the color on, it just has an outline.

**Note:**
You should replace the `OutlineButton` with `RaisedButton`.

For Text color you can use `style` property of the `Text` widget.

A little example code would be as following:

```
ButtonTheme(
height: 8.0,
buttonColor: Colors.red,
child: RaisedButton(
         color: Colors.blue,
         child: Text(
           'Button',
           style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
          onPressed: () {},
       ),
)
```

Comment: can you also tell me how to chane the button color

Comment: Also, If it has worked for you and resolved your question, take some time to upvote and accept the answer.